Non-italic punctuation in theorems
With \usepackage{amsmath}, we get a theorem like:
Theorem. Let $a$ and $b$ denote the legs of a triangle and let $c$ be the hypotenuse; then $a^2+b^2=c^2$ (where d^2 denotes multiplication of $d$ by itself in the group of real numbers).
How can we introduce a command in our preamble to make all punctuation (including parentheses) non-italic? It should look like:
Theorem. Let $a$ and $b$ denote the legs of a triangle and let $c$ be the hypotenuse; then $a^2+b^2=c^2$ (where d^2 denotes multiplication of $d$ by itself in the group of real numbers).
Thus, the period, semicolon, and parentheses are non-italic.

Please look at section 4 of the documentation of amsthm, in particular \theoremstyle and \newtheoremstyle.

I don't think there is such a setting. The ()' being italic is a feature of the font.

I know of only one font set that provides the feature, namely NewTX.
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[amsthm,theoremfont]{newtx}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Let $a$ and $b$ denote the legs of a triangle and let $c$ be the hypotenuse; 
then $a^2+b^2=c^2$ (where $d^2$ denotes multiplication of $d$ by itself in 
the field of real numbers).
\end{theorem}

\end{document}

The option twocolumn is used just to make a narrower picture.

I recently learned that luaotfload allows to build an “all caps” font variant on the fly. Maybe it could also provide for upright punctuation…

Is there anything else we can do? If I want Latin modern, I may add to the preamble: \renewcommand{\,}{{\normalfont{,}}}. Everything then works out. But is there anyway to not have to write the \,? If not, that's all right.

@John Sorry, no. I wouldn't bother with commas; semicolon, colon and parentheses can be dealt with by using \textup{<char>}, I'd likely just make parentheses upright, though.

A variant of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/719266/13492, if you want the body of theorems to be in a true slanted font (rather than Italic), yet punctuation still upright:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage[thmslshape]{newtx}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[bodyfont=\thfamily]{thmstyle}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, style=thmstyle]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
    Let $a$ and $b$ denote the legs of a triangle and let $c$ be the hypotenuse; 
then $a^2+b^2=c^2$ (where $d^2$ denotes multiplication of $d$ by itself in 
the field of real numbers).
\end{theorem}

\end{document} 


